# counting the sum of the degrees in an undirected graph

Tags: graph, pseudocode

here is my pseudocode:

```
for all u in V:
  degree[u]=0
  for all (u,w) in E:
    degree[u] = degree[u]+1
for all u in V:
  twodegree[u]=0
  for all (u,w) in E:
    twodegree[u]=twodegree[u]+degree[w]
```

this code attempts to count the sum of the degrees (degrees - # of neighbors u has or the # of edges incident upon it) of u's neighbors in an undirected graph. however i am having trouble understanding the two for loops can someone please explain what exactly is  degree[u] = degree[u]+1 and twodegree[u] = twodegree[u]+degree[w] doing, (i know its counting the sum of the degrees, but i just don't see it how) can someone please explain how this algorithm works in terms of u and w?

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm assumes that the vertices are represented as indexes in a list V. The edges are represented as tuples in a list E. I would assume this algorithm is for directed edges based on the "for all (u,w) in E:". A directed edge is an edge that only goes in one direction, so in a tuple (u,w), u would be the node that the edge is leaving to go to w.

```
    #first loop will calculate the number of edges directly adjacent to each vertex
    for all u in V:
      degree[u]=0  # initializes the number to 0
      for all (u,w) in E:  #find all tuples that contain u
        degree[u] = degree[u]+1 #add 1 for each edge in list
    # The second loop will calculate a slightly different metric but
    # it follows the same algorithm as the first
    for all u in V:
      twodegree[u]=0
      for all (u,w) in E:
        twodegree[u]=twodegree[u]+degree[w]
```

The "for all (u,w) in E:" contains an implied conditional that creates a sub list of E that only contains tuples with u as the first element.